# Yii - Pass filtered CGridView data to a PDF format

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

I have a web application that uses CGridView to display filtered data from the $model based on user-entered search parameters.

My goal is for the user to be able to hit a button to export the filtered data to a PDF.

In order to accomplish this I'm using the extension [yii-pdf.](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/pdf)

Do I need to pass the information stored in the CActiveDataProvider array to be used in a separate controller and view for the PDF creation?

It seems easier to use the same controller/action and render the data into a view that can then be exported to PDF.  But, alas, I cannot figure out how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

**_search View:**

```
<div class="wide form"> 
<?php 
     $form = $this->beginWidget('GxActiveForm', array(
    'action' => Yii::app()->createUrl($this->route),
    'method' => 'get',
    )); 
?>                
  <!-- Search Fields here -->    
  <!-- Search and Export to PDF buttons -->
  <div class="row buttons">
      <?php echo GxHtml::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Search')); ?>
      <?php echo GxHtml::button(Yii::t('app', 'PDF'),  array('id' => 'exportToPdf')); ?>
  </div>    
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>   
</div><!-- search-form -->
```

**_pdf View**

```
<div class="pdfContainer" id="pdfPage">    
  <div class="pdfHeader">
    <img src="images/logo.png" style="float:left; text-align: top;"></img>
    <div class="pdfTitle" style="text-align: right; float: right;">                    
       <h3>Service Report</h3>                    
    </div>
  </div><!-- header -->    
  <?php echo "Prepared by: ".Yii::app()->user->name."\n" ?>           
  <?php **//Possibly echo contents here?** ?>   
  <div class="clear"></div>    
    <div class="pdfFooter">         
    </div><!-- footer -->    
  </div><!-- page -->
</div>
```

**controller/action**

```
public function actionPdf(){       
    $this->layout='pdf';
    /* mPDF */
    $mPDF1 = Yii::app()->ePdf->mpdf();

    /* render (full page) */
    $mPDF1->WriteHTML($this->render('pdf', array(), true));

    /* renderPartial (only 'view' of current controller) */
    $mPDF1->WriteHTML($this->renderPartial('pdf', array(), true));

    /* Outputs ready PDF */
    $mPDF1->Output();      
}
```

**admin View:**

```
<?php        
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('search', "       
   $('#exportToPdf').click(function(){
   window.location = '". $this->createUrl('Weeklyservicereport/pdf') . "?' + $(this).parents('form').serialize() + '&export=true';
   return false;
});           

$('.search-form form').submit(function(){
    $('#weeklyservicereport-grid').yiiGridView('update', {
        data: $(this).serialize()
    });
    return false;
    });
    ");
?>
<div class="search-form" style="display:block">               
    <?php $this->renderPartial('_search', array('model' => $model,)); ?>           
</div> <!-- Search Form -->
/* Gridview Widget */  
<?php $this->widget('application.components.widgets.tlbExcelView', array(
    'id'            => 'weeklyservicereport-grid',
    'dataProvider'  => $model->search(),
     .....
     .....
    'columns'=>array(
        /* Column names */
    ),
 )); 
?>
```

Comment: As far as i remember you need to render this file first and then pass html to pdf. So what is the problem? Make button in CGridview to export pdf and do `$this_renderpartial('mypdfview', array('dataProvider'=>$dataProvider))` or render or even you can make `renderInternal`. Then reform it to pdf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're pretty close of the solution, I will write here the logic that you can use.

1. Create a view for your PDF header;
2. Create a view for your PDF footer;
3. Create a view for your Gridview;

**view: _pdf_header.php**

```
<div class="pdfHeader">
  <img src="images/logo.png" style="float:left; text-align: top;"></img>
  <div class="pdfTitle" style="text-align: right; float: right;">                    
     <h3>Service Report</h3>                    
  </div>
</div>
```

**view: _pdf_footer.php**

```
<div class="pdfFooter">
  <h5>Your Footer Page</h5>
</div>
```

**view: _gridview.php**

```
<?php $this->widget('application.components.widgets.tlbExcelView', array(
    'id'            => 'weeklyservicereport-grid',
    'dataProvider'  => $dataProvider,
    'columns'       => array( /*YOUR COLUMNS */   ),
));
?>
```

In your actionPdf, you just render partial the views, as suggested by @ineersa:

```
public function actionPdf(){      

    $this->layout      = 'pdf';
    $model             = new Model();
    $model->attributes = $_GET['Model']; /* to execute the filters (if is the case) */
    $dataProvider      = $model->search();

    /* if yu want to ignore the pagination and retrieve all records */
    $dataProvider->pagination = false; 

    $mPDF1 = Yii::app()->ePdf->mpdf();

    $mPDF1->WriteHTML($this->renderPartial('_pdf_header', array(), true));

    $mPDF1->WriteHTML($this->renderPartial('_gridview', array('dataProvider' => $dataProvider), true));

    $mPDF1->WriteHTML($this->renderPartial('_pdf_footer', array(), true));

    $mPDF1->Output();      
}
```

Reference:

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/15677-printing-a-cgridview/

Comment: Thanks @Eduardo.  I'm working with this right now, will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Ok!  This got me headed in the right direction.  I made a couple edits in your suggested solution to show what ended up working for me.  Thanks!